# Why am I getting class not found exception with AndroidJavaClass?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .detectAll()
     .penaltyLog()
     .build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I tried the following code, but generates exception for class not found for ThreadPolicy

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        using (AndroidJavaClass strictModeClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.StrictMode"))
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass threadpolicy = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy"))
            {

                    AndroidJavaObject Builder = threadpolicy.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("Builder");
                    AndroidJavaObject permitall = Builder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("permitAll");
                    AndroidJavaObject build = permitall.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("build");
                    strictModeClass.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setThreadPolicy", build);

            }
        }
        #endif
```

Answer (score 3):

It simply can't find the class on the Java side. This can be caused my misspelling, ProGuard obfuscating the class name or the package and plugin with the class not included in your project.

In your case, you get "class not found" exception at `AndroidJavaClass("android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy")` because `ThreadPolicy` is **not** a package but an **inner class** so to differentiate between these two, you have to tell JRE that you are looking for an inner class and this can be done by replacing the `"."` in the inner class with the `"$"` symbol.

Replace

```
AndroidJavaClass threadpolicy = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy")
```

with

```
AndroidJavaClass threadpolicy = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy");
```